# Can I convert a .dxf to .png or .jpg with a command tool?

Tags: command-line, package-management

I'm looking for some command line tool that allows me to convert dxf to any other format.

Comment: Take a look at freecad and librecad: `sudo apt install freecad librecad`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a number of vector drawing programs that support DXF files to varying degrees, and have commandline convert capabilities, including `dia`, `inkscape`, and even `libreoffice`.

- **dia** appears to support dxf input and png output e.g.

  ```
  dia jcsample.dxf -e jcsample.png
  ```

  or, with explicit output dimensions,

  ```
  dia jcsample.dxf -s 744x1052 -e jcsample.png
  ```

  however the result was an empty file in the first case and corrupted in the second, on the sample file that I tried - you may have better luck.
- **inkscape** also appears to support the same functionality e.g.

  ```
  inkscape -f jcsample.dxf --export-png=jcsample.png
  ```

  however again the result was unreadable. What *did* work for inkscape was converting to Encapsulated PostScript first

  ```
  inkscape -f jcsample.dxf --export-eps=jcsample.eps
  ```

  and then converting eps to png or jpeg, for example using Ghostscript

  ```
  gs -sDEVICE=png16m -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dSAFER -sOutputFile=jcsample.png jcsample.eps
  ```

  or

  ```
  gs -sDEVICE=jpeg -dJPEGQ=100 -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dSAFER -r100 -sOutputFile=jcsample.jpg jcsample.eps
  ```

  [*Note that the same trick did not appear to work for `dia`, even though it also supports PostScript output*]

  The downside with `inkscape` is that the dxf import filter pops up a dialog to confirm the default scaling and encoding, making it not truly non-interactive: as far as I know there is not currently a way to prevent that, although there is an [outstanding feature request](https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/1266193) for it (adding the `-z` or `--without-gui` switch doesn't seem to help).
- **libreoffice** appears to work directly to either png or jpg

  ```
  libreoffice --headless --convert-to png jcsample.dxf

  libreoffice --headless --convert-to jpg jcsample.dxf
  ```

  however on the same sample file, the resulting images were scaled to fit centrally in a portrait page; again, the solution may be to use an intermediate vector format e.g. pdf

  ```
  libreoffice --headless --convert-to pdf jcsample.dxf
  pdfcrop jcsample.pdf
  gs -sDEVICE=png16m -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dSAFER -sOutputFile=jcsample.png jcsample-crop.pdf
  ```

Sorry this isn't a one-size-fits-all answer - but hopefully it will give you some things to try.

Comment: apparently there's no perfect solution, but these workarounds work just fine